# Is it possible to exclude hidden files when uploading a directory?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, file-upload, hidden-files

When a user selects a directory from which to upload all documents, it might contain hidden files created by windows like `thumbs.db`

Is there any way of detecting, either on the front end or back end, whether a particular file was hidden?

Currently handling files uploads with `bootstrap-vue` and `typescript`

```
<b-form-file id="documentFolder"
             accept="allowedFileTypes"
             style="display:none;"
             @change="handleFolderSelected"
             :directory="true" />

handleFolderSelected(files: Array<File>) {
    // build form data - post files
}
```

I assume its just using a regular [file input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file), but can't see anything useful there either

---

I'm recieving the files as `IFormFile`s using `.net-5.0`

Is this possible at all, or do I need to simply inform the user that they should remove all hidden files?

Comment: I highly doubt it, in a web context. Maybe just keep a list of commonly hidden files like thumbs.db and discard them at the server end. Or provide an uploader tool that runs locally and can make the decision